# Trying to understand this piece of c code but just cant get it

Tags: c, pointers, structure, memory-address

I have been googling for couple of hours now for explanation for following code but just couldn't find, appreciating if someone can help me.

I have defined memory location like (address is just sample),

```
#define address (0x000001)
```

then i have a struct

```
typedef struct{
int a;
int c;
int f;
} foo;
```

and last (this part i can't figure out) I have definition like

```
#define foo__ ( (foo *) address)
```

does this mean that I'm creating macro whereby I can access elements of structure `foo` and that `foo` structure begins at 0x000001?

I know that the code works - have tested it but there is no use if I cant understand what it does.

Edit. Sorry for unclear information on question - yea its LPC microcontroller by NXP which is used in embedded environment - should told that in the first place and - my bad.

Thanks for answers and commends - I figured it out now.

Comment: what does "works" mean here?

Comment: `foo * const foo__ = (foo *) address;` would be the better solution.

Comment: Like @AnttiHaapala seems to suggest, it's unlikely that works. If you try something like **printf("a=%d\n",(foo__)->a);** then I'd guess it'll segfault due to that absolute 0x000001 address. If you'd, say, declared **foo thisfoo={1,2,3};** and then **define foo__ (&thisfoo);** then I'd guess it would print **a=1**.

Comment: It **can work** for memory mapped devices on an embedded systems. But certainly not for any random address...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us about your target platform. Is it some microcontroller or some embedded device?

Answer (score 3):

It creates a macro, such that if you use `foo__`, it will assume an instance of that `typedef'd` `struct` exists at (in this example) `0x000001`.

So, if an instance *does* exist there, and you can access it, you'll be able to access those elements accordingly. However, there's no protection here and it's really up to you to decide if that's sensible and safe for you to attempt.